# Finite Metric Space

Tags: metric-spaces

> In finite metric space all sets are open

Is it true because all singletons are open and the union of them is open too?

Comment: yes exactly! very good

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's true, but another way:

In any metric space, finite or not, all singletons are closed. So finite sets are closed.

In a finite metric space, any subset has a finite (hence closed) complement. So all sets are open.

Comment: I read your proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548488/show-that-the-singleton-set-is-open-in-a-finite-metric-spce

Basically the proof says that a singleton in finite metric space is open because for all point in the neighborhood of the singleton (and there are none) $N_{s}\subseteq \{s\}$?

Comment: @gbox The point of that proof was that the OP wanted to use the open-ball definition of openness in a metric space. So I defined a radius for an open ball.

Comment: Yes, but in the end you showed that the ball only contains the singleton so why the ball is open?

Comment: @gbox Because $\forall p \in \{x\} \exists r > 0: B(p,r) \subseteq \{x\}$, which is the definition of open sets  in a metric space.

Comment: @gbox Or use the lemma: an open ball $(p,r)$ is an open subset of $(X,d)$ in any metric space.

Comment: this is what I meant to say, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $M=\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\}$ be a finite metric space.

Let $A=\{x_1\}$ Then $A^c=\{x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_n\}$ is a finite set, hence closed. Therefore, $A$ is open.

Similarly, all singletons are open.

Now, let $B$ be any subset of $M.$ Then $B$ is a finite union of open sets(singletons), hence open.

In general, all subsets of a metric space are open if singletons are open.

**Edit 1:** To show a finite set is closed, it is sufficient to show that any singleton is closed (since finite union of closed sets is closed)

Let $X$ be a metric space and $x \in X$. We need to show $\{x\}$ is closed. It suffices to show that $\{x\}^c$ is open. 
Let $ y \in \{x\}^c.$ Then $y\neq x.$ Hence, $d(x,y)>0.$ Let $$r=\frac{d(x,y)}{2}>0$$
Then $B(y,r) \subseteq \{x\}^c.$ This shows $\{x\}^c$ is open.

**Edit 2:** Let $z \in B(y,r)$. Then $$d(z,y)<r=\frac{d(x,y)}{2}<d(x,y)$$
Hence, $z \neq x$. Therefore, $z \in \{x\}^c.$
As $z \in B(y,r)$ was arbitrary, therefore $B(y,r) \subseteq \{x\}^c.$

Comment: Why $A^c$ is closed? because it is finite?

Comment: A finite set is always closed.

Comment: Why can we say (or be sure) that $B(y,r) \subseteq \{x\}^c$?

Comment: Ok I got it, because we took $\frac{d(x,y)}{2}$ so for every point in the ball let say $z$  $d(z,y)<\frac{d(x,y)}{2}$